# react-native dynamic alarm clock

Tags: android, ios, react-native, alarm

I'm making a planning app, where the user have the option to set an alarm "x hours before task starts" - the issue here is that sometimes the task might get rescheduled during the night and then the app should reset to the new tasks start time even if the user is not inside the app.

I solved this with a background worker which periodically calls an api for the current users next booked task and sets a notification with an alarm sound.

This works sort of OK, but if the user is on "Do not disturb" he/she will not hear the alarm.

What are my other options for a more "real" alarm which goes through the DND? I have not really found any good libraries for this. Also is a background worker that periodically calls an API the best way to solve this?

Greetings from a beginner in react-native.